# OutputDebugString + DebugView = not tabs!

Tags: c++, debugging, outputdebugstring, debugview

I am dumping \t delimited data using using OutputDebugString and then use ex-Sysinternals DebugView to capture it.

The problem is that all the data in DebugView appear to be space delimited, hence I need to perfrorm CTRL+H "\x20" "t" to replace spaces with the tabs before I can use it (I really need tab delimited data).

Is there anyway to tell DebugView not to replace tabs with spaces? 
Or maybe there is a better tool available to capture output of the OutputDebugString function?

Any ideas are very welcome!

Comment: Have you tried logging to a file? (File\Log to file...)

Comment: tried, didn't help - it outputs \x20-s, not \t-s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems this is a "feature" in DebugView. I have tried with [Hoo Wintail](http://www.hootech.com/WinTail/) and this dude collects tabs without any problem. So I see 3 solutions:

1. You get [Hoo Wintail](http://www.hootech.com/WinTail/) (highly **recommended**)
2. You write your on tool (look [here](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/outputdebugstring.html) for some idea how to do it or even get a [complete one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/OutputDebugString.aspx))
3. You redirect to file.

I strongly vote for option **1**.

Comment: Looks interesting. Really like the idea of realtime monitoring of trace log files located at FTP. What could be really cool (not sure if such tool exist or not) - to be able watch logs which are located on the remote unix servers accessible with SFTP.

Can someone recomend such a tool?

Answer (score 1):

Why not write them on a local log-file ? (only on debug mode ?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple spaces instead of a tab.

Answer (score 0):

DebugOutput and DebugView are intended for situations as implied by their name: debug.  They are not intended to replace file-save functionality.

You are probably in the situation where analyzing the debug output means analyzing the tab-delimited format.  Find another character that can be used instead of tab, e.g. | or @ or ^.
Then open the debug output in an advanced editor (e.g. UltraEdit) and convert the character back to Tab.

Comment: This is what I do now. I though I could eliminate that extra step.